# How to compare if any items from a list in adjacent rows of the dataframe match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a pandas dataframe that contains a list in column DIAG_CD (<class 'list'>):

Here is a sample, but the data set can potentially have up to 100,000 rows.

```
            DIAG_CODE
0          [  "M9901",   "M9902",   "M9903",   "M5412"]

1          [  "M9901"]

2          [  "M9901",   "M9902",   "M9903",   "M5412"]

3          [  "M9901",   "M9902",   "M9903",   "M542"]

...

20    [  "M542",   "M9902",   "M9903",   "M25519",  ...

21    [  "M542",   "M9902",   "M9903",   "M25519",  ...
```

My goal is to see if any items in the list on two adjacent rows match. For example, does list from row 0 have any items in list on row 1, and the answer is yes. Similarly, row 1 is a match for row 2.

I have tried different things but cannot make it work.

I tried this but it produced an error - *AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'*:

`zipped = zip(df1['DIAG_CD'], df1['DIAG_CD'].shift(1))
df1['diagCodeMatch'] = [int(bool(set(a.split(',')) & set(b.split(',')))) for a, b in
zipped]`

This produces an error as well - `df1['DIAG_CD']& df1['DIAG_CD'].shift(1)`

*TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'*

I am pretty new to python and pandas so any help is much appreciated.

This what I currently have:

```
df = pd.read_parquet("samplefile.parquet", engine='pyarrow')
print(df.head(20))
#remove newline characters
df.replace(to_replace=[r"\\t|\\n|\\r", "\t|\n|\r"], value=["",""], regex=True, inplace=True)
df['intersection'] = [list(set(a).intersection(set(b))) for a, b in zip(df['DIAG_CD'], df['DIAG_CD'].shift(1))]
```

Comment: Please post a clean reproducible sample. ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems like you're storing lists within each row, there are a number of ways of doing it, but one way efficient way is to turn the lists into sets and use `not set(a).isdisjoint(b)` to test for whether they have any shared elements or not. As such, you could do the below:

```
for i in range(df.DIAG_CD.shape[0]-1):
    mutual_elements_exist = not set([df.DIAG_CD.iloc[i]]).isdisjoint([df.DIAG_CD.iloc[i+1]])
    print(f'Shared elements between row_{i}_and_row_{i+1} is {mutual_elements_exist}')
```

This will return `True` if any values are shared and `False` if none of them are. I added the print function because it is unclear what it is exactly that you would like to achieve with this. There are quite a few different ways of grouping the results as well, but due to the absence of information I left it at this.

EDIT: I have amended the issue and changed it so that you could run it directly.

Comment: There are many columns in the data frame (name = df) including start and end dates. I am trying to make a decision based on the fact that if the start date changed but the DIAG_CD column had a matching element from the previous row's list (any element) then I take an action. I have the data frame grouped and sorted on several columns. I tried your code but got the following error:   File "<ipython-input-223-44c6301066f3>", line 4
    i in range(df1.shape[0]-1):
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Is the "df1" a series? What's the output of running df1.shape? The point of that is just to find the range of the rows.

Comment: It was missing the keyword for, adding it fixed it. Yes it is a series. When I do a shape on the data frame I get 10,000 which is the number of rows in the data frame. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It is saying True for every single row, however, looking at the data that is not the case.

Comment: That is strange as that wasn't the case for the dataframe that I made up and tried. I will check it out for you later.

Comment: Could you show me how you're using the code? Because I tried it again and it is yielding correct results. For instance, for the df shown here:
```df = pd.DataFrame({0: [[1,2,3],[1,1,3],[4,5,6]],})```, the snippet yields ```Shared elements between row_0_and_row_1 is True``` and
```Shared elements between row_1_and_row_2 is False```

Maybe I am misunderstanding what it is you're trying to achieve? If ANY elements in the adjacent rows match, it will return true, else it returns false.

Comment: What I mean is if for example, in your data frame 1 and 3 from the first row are matching the next row so it is true but , nothing is matching between 1,1,3 and 4,5,6 so it should be false. I can send you a sample file if it helps. The data in parqet file itself seems to be a string. When I run this code (df\
.sample(100)\
.applymap(type)\
.astype(str) == "<class 'list'>")\
.any(0) I get  -DIAG_CD              False indicating it may not be a list but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: You are right, and as you can see it returned False for the second permutation. If you'd like I could take a look at a sample of your data and see what the difference is.

Comment: Here is a link to the file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nBdGic5mBfQ58uLTyZVmW2Ll_0IXRetU/view?usp=sharing .
To read the file  df = pd.read_parquet("samplefile.parquet", engine='pyarrow').
#remove newline characters
df.replace(to_replace=[r"\\t|\\n|\\r", "\t|\n|\r"], value=["",""], regex=True, inplace=True)

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake in that I forgot to account for that we're dealing with strings. In calling ```set()``` as I outlined previously,  every element in each row was split into their letters and thus returned ```True``` everywhere. This is easily fixed by adding ```[]``` to each row, thus preventing this from happening, i.e. ```not set([df.DIAG_CD.iloc[i]]).isdisjoint([df.DIAG_CD.iloc[i+1]])``` I have amended my answer above as well.